# Load a process into RAM, but don't execute?

Tags: linux, signals, scheduling

Is there a way to load a process into RAM, but somehow tell the scheduler not to execute it? The aim being to have the system read the binary from disk, allocate the pages in RAM for the code, but not to immediately jump into the code to start executing it. The intention to be to start it at some later time.

The below approximates to this, but allows some amount of execution before the signal is delivered to pause the process:

```
$ /path/to/program &; kill -STOP $!
```

I assume there's some part of code execution that involves pulling in libraries and other "setup" before the first line of my actual program is executed. I don't mind if these steps are run or not. We can assume I have root and can make any changes to the system to support this task.

Having played with `gdb`, I assume this could do what I ask in some way. This would suffice, but ideally I'd have a way to do this without needing to have anything running alongside my process.

In response to comments, I suspect the load-when-needed issue would indeed frustrate this plan. I was hoping to load the code into RAM, modify the file, and then let the process execute. The code in RAM is now different to the code on disk. If the process's first job was to hash the file, it would now get the "wrong" hash, even though it's running the "correct" code.

Comment: Binary/library code is read from the disk on as-needed basis (with by default 128KB prefetch), so I've no idea how to achieve what you're asking for. Pages are allocated for code also on as-needed basis, e.g. imagine a web browser which after running will allocate a ton of them and it's not possible to know in advance how much it needs. What exactly are you trying to solve? You've got an issue I guess and this is your first idea of solving it only it might not even be necessary or it's just the wrong approach.

Comment: Just to give you an example why what you're looking for is terribly wrong. Multiple archivers on Windows allow to create self extracting archives which can be as huge as 2^64-1 bytes. Imagine you've got such an archive which exceeds the amount of RAM on your PC. How will you possibly preload it into RAM?

Comment: Just to check: This is _different_ from copying the executable from disk and into a RAM-based filesystem to later execute it from there, right? I don't quite see the benefit of doing what you're asking. Is it to somehow hide the fact that you are about to run a particular piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably won’t achieve what you’re *really* after (as explained in the comments, binaries are loaded as needed), but it will stop a process as soon as it starts, and have it wait for a `SIGCONT`.

Place the following in a file, say `stop.c`:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

__attribute__ ((constructor)) void stoponstart() {
  kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
}
```

Build it as a shared library:

```sh
gcc stop.c -o stop.so -fPIC -shared
```

Then preload it whenever you want to “start and pause” a program:

```sh
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/stop.so foo
```

When run from a shell, this will actually put the process in the background, and you can then really start it with `fg`.