# Is it possible to load up a binary into ram, without executing it?

Tags: chrome, executable, cache, ram, exec

Like I will use google chrome whenever I use linux (most probably) But I don't want it to auto start when ever I open it. I could open it manually, but I have HDD so it is pain to load for the first time, so I wanna know if there is a way to load chrome from HDD to RAM without really running it, Just load, and make cache in RAM.

Comment: How about a ramdisk ? Or depending on your linux directly use `/dev/shm`. But might be complex to add all dependent libraries, too.

Comment: See the comments on https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/708799/86440

Answer (score 1):

I use [`vmtouch`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/vmtouch.8.html).

> `vmtouch` opens every file provided on the command line and maps it into virtual memory with `mmap(2)`. The mappings are opened read-only. It recursively crawls any directories and does the same to all files it finds within them.
>
> […]
>
> `-t`
> Touch virtual memory pages. Reads a byte from each page of the file. If the page is not resident in memory, a page fault will be generated and the page will be read from disk into the file system's memory cache.
>
> Note: Although each page is guaranteed to have been brought into memory, the page might be evicted from memory by the time the `vmtouch` command completes.

To overcome what the above note states, I use `vmtouch -l` (as root):

> `-l`
> Lock pages into physical memory. This option works the same as `-t` except it calls `mlock(2)` on all the memory mappings and doesn't close the descriptors when finished. At the end of the crawl, if successful, `vmtouch` will block indefinitely. The files will be locked in physical memory until the `vmtouch` process is killed.

My usage case is to preemptively cache relatively large media files from a relatively slow NFS server over a relatively slow network connection. It works very well. It should work for you. You just need to identify the files you want to load. This question may be useful: [How to find out the dynamic libraries executable loads when run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120015/108618)

Comment: See also `memlockd` which I believe does something similar (I've not tried it myself)